# evaluation of nested { { } } incorrect/ (matrix/array in block of textstyle) seems to be buggy

Tags: bug, mathjax

I tried to nest textattributes and matrices and this seems to be a bug.
An array, assumed to be in mathfrac is in the curly brackets:

In principle: `\mathfrac { TEXT array{ TEXT,TEXT,... } TEXT }`
comes out to be

$\small \mathfrak {
     ABC
     \begin{bmatrix}  
              \text{this  is  mathfrak}       & \text{this should be  mathfrak}  \\ 
              \text{this should be  mathfrak} & \text{this should be  mathfrak} \\ 
              \text{this should be  mathfrak} & \text{ it should be up to here!} \\ 
    \end{bmatrix}
     \text{ surprise: here it is mathfrak again!} } $

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried something similar on my local $\LaTeX$ distribution (MiKTeX).  I gave it this:

```
$$\mathfrak{
  mathematical
  \quad
  \begin{bmatrix}
    this & is \\
    in & mathfrak
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad
  fraktur}$$
```

and it came out like this:
$$
\mathfrak{
mathematical}
\quad
  \begin{bmatrix}
this & is \\
in & mathfrak
  \end{bmatrix}
\quad
\mathfrak{fraktur}
$$
which differs from MathJax's handling of it:
$$\mathfrak{
  mathematical
  \quad
  \begin{bmatrix}
    this & is \\
    in & mathfrak
  \end{bmatrix}
  \quad
  fraktur}$$

I have no idea how $\LaTeX$ is *supposed* to handle this sort of construction, but it might be that certain math environments are designed to override the current (math-)fonts with a neutral form.  (I would be interested to hear if any $\LaTeX$ distributions handle this differently.)

<strike>At any rate, though there is a discrepancy in the way this construction is handled — and it also doesn't match what you expected to happen — I don't think there is much that can be done about it here on SE.  Perhaps mention it at the [MathJax issues forum](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues).</strike>

Comment: The MathJax developers follow this site, so it's half-fine. (See you tomorrow, by the way)

Comment: Thanks @Asaf: you learn something everyday, I guess.  (If you're braving the cold weather tomorrow, I'll be around the Archive.)

Comment: (Here it's a bit cold, but a lot windy and full of dust. I suppose plain cold is a slight improvement)

Comment: (Well, dusty and full of grad missiles. Not to be confused with grad students, which are also abundant.)